# How to add and remove to 2 variables

Tags: javascript, variables

im trying to add and remove to 2 different variables in a code for a incremental game.
here is the code:

```
$("#autoPayCheckBuy").click(function () {
    if (totalClicks >= 50) {
        totalClicks -= 50;
        totalMoneys += 50;
        $("#total_moneys").text(totalMoneys);
        $("#total_clicks").text(totalClicks);
    }
});
```

and here is the code for the money/clicks:

var totalClicks = 0;

var totalMoneys = 100;

sorry that i cant give a exact problem, i just cant find a problem in the code :(

Comment: It's ok if you can't describe the exact problem, but you haven't even tried. We don't know what to look for here without you telling us.

Comment: Ok, on click you check if totalClicks it's > or = 50 and you remove 50 to totalClcks and you add 50 to totalMoneys. Ok ok, but what is the PROBLEM? What you want to obtain??

Comment: i need to obtain 100 "money" but check if i have enough "clicks" and then remove 50 clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a problem in the code either. What exactly is your problem? Maybe you are missing the d.ready ?

```
var totalClicks = 0;
var totalMoneys = 100;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#autoPayCheckBuy").click(function () {
        if (totalClicks < 50) return false;
        totalClicks -= 50;
        totalMoneys += 50;
        $("#total_moneys").text(totalMoneys);
        $("#total_clicks").text(totalClicks);
    });
});
```